# cannot convert 'std::vector<std::vector<char> >' to 'int'

Tags: visual-c++

In main

```
vector<vector<char>> map(x+2,vector<char>(y+2));

Read_map(x, y, map, &task);
```

In head.h

```
void Read_map(int x,int y, vector<vector<char>> &map, int *task);
```

after compiler in main
it say cannot convert `std::vector<std::vector<char> >` to `int`

and in head.h
it say 'vector' has not been declared

whether we need to declared in head.h `#include<vector>`?

can anyone tell me how to solve it?
please

thanks

Comment: Are you including `head.h` in whichever file you're using `Read_map`?

Comment: Please share a sample demonstrating the issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.